# Package power limit notification?

Tags: 11.10, hibernate, intel

I started receiving this error recently when I **hibernate** my Ubuntu 11.10:

`CPU 4: Package power limit motications (total events: 988)` etc for all my 8 cpus/threads.

My configuration is [such](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/lemu4) with i5/8gb ram. What does this error mean? overheating?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a Core i5 or i7 with *Intel Turbo Boost*? On my i7, it seems like those messages appear when the Turbo Boost reaches the power maximum. Shouldn't be a need to wory.

Comment: is there any way to switch them off I have a lot of them on my server just a screen full of them